# All subseries convergent is absolutely convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

By definition i have; Given a normed space $X$, a series $\sum x_n$ is subseries convergent if for all sequence $n_1<n_2<\ldots < n_k<$ then the the subseries $\sum_k x_{n_k}$ is convergent.

I have two problems.
a) Prove that if $X$ is finite dimensional then all subseries convergent in $X$ is absolutely convergent.

b) If $X$ is infinite dimensional then the statement above is no true. (Hint, consider $X=c_0$)

My attempt was:

a) As $X$ is finite dimensonal then $X$ is Banach space. Now, i want to prove that if $\sum x_n$ is subseries convergent implies that $\sum ||x_n||_X $ is convergent.
Hence given the $\sum x_n$ subseries convergent implies that $\sum_k x_{n_k}<\infty$ for all subsequence $n_1<\ldots n_k<$. (In particular for the original serie $\sum x_n)$ From one side i have that exist a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $X$ and every norm in $X$ is equivalent to each other.

I want to study the series $\sum_{j}^{\infty}||x_j||_X $. I want to show that the partial sums are a Cauchy sequence. Let us $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||_X$ then for $n>m$

$\left|\sum_{i=1}^m ||x_i||_X-\sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||_X\right|\leq \sum_m^n||x_i||_X$
How can continued?

For b) why fail? Thank you and excuse me, i am stuck

Comment: For a) apply that property for one-dimensional space  i.e. for numerical series (this a nontrivial theorem). Then use cartesian product. For b) consider $x=\sum {1\over n} e_n,$ where $e_n$ is the standard basis in $c_0.$

Comment: Thank you @RyszardSzwarc, please what you mean by cartesian product.

Comment: I was thinking, the series that  i am studying is a numerical series, then is enought to show that the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence  or is monotone and bounded and as $\mathbb R$ is complete the series converge. So, i am studying the sequence $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n ||x_j||$. This sequences is monotone because every term is positive, and i am with problems in show that is bounded.

Comment: You should prove that if the series $\sum x_{n_k}$ is convergent for any increasing sequence of indices $n_k$ then $\sum \|x_n\|<\infty.$ For numerical series with real terms choose all the indices $n=n_k$ such that $x_n\ge 0. $ The remaining terms are all negative, and can be indexed as $m_k.$ By assumption $\sum x_{n_k}<\infty $ and $\sum (-x_{m_k})<\infty.$ Thus $\sum|x_n|<\infty. $ If the space $X$ is finite dimensional it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^N.$ Hence we can apply the one-dimensional result coordinatewise.

Comment: I am confuse, why all subseries of  $\sum \frac{1}{n}e_n$ converge, i mean $e_n=(0,\ldots, 1,0,\ldots)$ in position $n$ is equal $1$. the subseries always is a subseries of the armonic series and the armonic series diverge right? I am with problems to understant how is a element, one term of the series is a sequence or is a real number? Thank you @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: Other thing, i am studying $\sum ||x_n||$ and the term is always $\geq 0$ then how can separate the terms positives and negative please

Comment: You separate positive and negative terms in the original series $\sum x_n.$  Read my previous comment: you have to apply the assumptions about subseries in order to prove the absolute convergence of the entire series.  Concerning b) the series $\sum {1\over n}e_n$ is convergent to $(1,{1\over 2},\ldots, {1\over n},\ldots ),$ an element of $c_0.$

Comment: Now it was clear, thank you so much @RyszardSzwarc